# how to build python application that contains a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run this script in a python shell it works perfectly but when I build the code and run the ".exe" file the application won't start.

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib,sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


master=Tk()
master.title("graphe")
master.geometry("700x650+100+100")
f=Figure((5,5),dpi=100)
a=f.add_subplot(111)
a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,5,6,8,9,10])
data=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=master)
data.show()
data.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

`setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable 
import sys 

base=None 
if(sys.platform=='win32'): 
    base="Win32GUI" 
setup(name='application', 
      options={"build_exe":{"packages": ["tkinter","matplotlib","numpy","PIL","math"]}}‌​, 
      version="1.1", 
      executables=[Executable("graphe.py",base=base)]
     )
```

Comment: Can you describe how you're building the code?

Comment: in the cmd : python setup.py build. setup.py is a file

Comment: What is printed to the error log?

Comment: There isn't an error log the thing is this code works correctly but when i build this code in order to have ".exe" file (because it's an application that i want it to work on other computers) it won't start and i'm pretty sure that the problem is at the figure and the matplotlib they won't work with tkinter on the ".exe" application

Comment: But i don't know what to do in order to work it out and i have to make this graph show